# Reuse model MVC

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following scenario, at the moment I retrieve an entire person including their addresses from an external service (which I have no control over). I only want to display one instance of the address then have a model to display the rest if needed. At the moment I pass the idea then do another lookup to the external service however as I already have the data this is inefficient.

Can anyone help with a good strategy to is the best way to transmit the list of addresses?

NB I retyped the code in a simplified form so please ignore any typos

Models

```
public class PersonModel
{
    Public int Id {get;set}
    Public String Name {get; set;}
    Public IEnumerable Address {get; set;}
    // Single Address from the collection 
    Public DisplayAddress {get;set;}
}

public class AddressesViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Address> Address { get; set; }
}
```

The View

```
@model PersonModel  
<span>@Model.Name</span>
<ol>
                        @if (Model.DisplayAddress != null)
                        {
                            <li>@Model.DisplayAddress.Line1</li>

                        <li>@Model.DisplayAddress.Line2</li>
                        <li>@Model.DisplayAddress.Line3 </li>

                        <li>@Model.DisplayAddress.Town</li>
                        <li>@Model.DisplayAddress.County</li>
                        <li>@Model.DisplayAddress.PostalCode</li>
                        <li>@Model.DisplayAddress.Country</li>
                        }
                    </ol>
 <a id="showalladdresses" title="View all addresses" href="#">View All Addressess</a>

@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#Modal').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 600,
            width: 800,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true
        });

        $('#showalladdresses').click(function () {
            $('#Modal').load("@Url.Action("ViewAddresses", new { id = Model.Id })", function () {
                $(this).dialog('open');
            });
            return false;
        });

    });

 }
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult PersonBanner(long? Id)
    {
        if (!Id.HasValue)
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "HomeController");


        var result = new PersonModel();
        result = unitOfWork.GetPersonSummaryDetails(Id.Value)


        return View(result);
    }
public ActionResult ViewAddresses(long Id)
    {

        var model = new AddressesViewModel
            {
             Address = unitOfWork.GetAddressesById(Id);
            };
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return PartialView(model);
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: You can insert the model into hidden elements in a form and perform a submit in the view which submits the whole form to the action of your choice as a parameter. Or was it something else you wanted to do?

Comment: When you get the Person object is it a single instance of a person or is it an IEnumerable?

Comment: Why not just render the addresses to a hidden `<div>` and use that as your modal dialog?

Comment: @RichardDeeming that is a perfect idea, cant beleve I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 0):

Its ok to get the data again. Just put the PatientSummaryDetails into the cache.

Answer (score 0):

> however as I already have the data this is inefficient.

No you don't already have it. As I understand it, `PersonBanner` and `ViewAddresses` are two separate HTTP requests: one a page request, the other via AJAX. Your web application is stateless, so on every request you need to load all the data you need.

If you find that you *really* need the performance, you can introduce a caching layer between your UI and your services that will cache a `PersonModel` on first request and return it from the cache on subsequent requests. Caching sometimes gives problems surrounding staleness of data, so only explore this if you need to.

Comment: I do take you point that that are separate requests, however as I have all the information from the first request, I think I will follow @Richard Deemings idea of using a hidden div.